# Sorting column with array in a dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I'm looking for a method to sort a dataframe by a column which consists of arrays. Below is my dataframe with index, arrays(a) and values (b).

```
index    a   b
0       [0]  0.014066
1       [1]  0.569054
2       [2]  0.379795
3       [3]  0.037084
4       [4]  0.699488
5       [5]  0.191816
6       [6]  0.107417
7    [0, 4]  0.008951
8    [0, 5]  0.002558
9    [0, 6]  0.002558
10   [1, 4]  0.448849
11   [1, 5]  0.089514
12   [1, 6]  0.030691
13   [2, 4]  0.217391
14   [2, 5]  0.095908
15   [2, 6]  0.066496
16   [3, 4]  0.024297
17   [3, 5]  0.003836
18   [3, 6]  0.007673
19   [0, 3]  0.000000
20   [1, 3]  0.000000
21   [2, 3]  0.000000
```

As seen the last 3 arrays are not sorted like the others. What I would like would be this:

```
index    a   b
0       [0]  0.014066
1       [1]  0.569054
2       [2]  0.379795
3       [3]  0.037084
4       [4]  0.699488
5       [5]  0.191816
6       [6]  0.107417
-> [0,3] here
7    [0, 4]  0.008951
8    [0, 5]  0.002558
9    [0, 6]  0.002558
-> [1,3] here
10   [1, 4]  0.448849
11   [1, 5]  0.089514
12   [1, 6]  0.030691
-> [2,3] here
13   [2, 4]  0.217391
14   [2, 5]  0.095908
15   [2, 6]  0.066496
16   [3, 4]  0.024297
17   [3, 5]  0.003836
18   [3, 6]  0.007673
```

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance! df.sort_values('a') doesn't seem to work. Only on the values in b.

Comment: Btw, providing a method to easily recreate the data would be appreciated.  Those lists make it annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to [@jpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414159/2336654) for getting me straight on using `len`

### use `loc` with `sorted` and `key` argument

```
m = {k: (len(v), tuple(v)) for k, v in df.a.items()}
df.loc[sorted(df.index, key=m.get)]

            a         b
index                  
0         [0]  0.014066
1         [1]  0.569054
2         [2]  0.379795
3         [3]  0.037084
4         [4]  0.699488
5         [5]  0.191816
6         [6]  0.107417
19     [0, 3]  0.000000
7      [0, 4]  0.008951
8      [0, 5]  0.002558
9      [0, 6]  0.002558
20     [1, 3]  0.000000
10     [1, 4]  0.448849
11     [1, 5]  0.089514
12     [1, 6]  0.030691
21     [2, 3]  0.000000
13     [2, 4]  0.217391
14     [2, 5]  0.095908
15     [2, 6]  0.066496
16     [3, 4]  0.024297
17     [3, 5]  0.003836
18     [3, 6]  0.007673
```

### Old Answer

```
df.loc[sorted(df.index, key=lambda i: (lambda t: (len(t), tuple(t)))(df.at[i, 'a']))]

            a         b
index                  
0         [0]  0.014066
1         [1]  0.569054
2         [2]  0.379795
3         [3]  0.037084
4         [4]  0.699488
5         [5]  0.191816
6         [6]  0.107417
19     [0, 3]  0.000000
7      [0, 4]  0.008951
8      [0, 5]  0.002558
9      [0, 6]  0.002558
20     [1, 3]  0.000000
10     [1, 4]  0.448849
11     [1, 5]  0.089514
12     [1, 6]  0.030691
21     [2, 3]  0.000000
13     [2, 4]  0.217391
14     [2, 5]  0.095908
15     [2, 6]  0.066496
16     [3, 4]  0.024297
17     [3, 5]  0.003836
18     [3, 6]  0.007673
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Your solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Data from jpp

```
from natsort import natsorted
natsorted(s)
Out[940]: [[0], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1], [2], [3, 6]]
```

Update

```
s.iloc[natsorted(range(len(s)), key=lambda k: (len(s[k]),s[k]))]
Out[997]: 
0       [0]
1       [1]
2       [2]
5    [0, 3]
3    [0, 4]
4    [3, 6]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. By the looks of the output, this puts [0, 3] before [1] etc. which wasn't exactly what I was looking for, or am I getting it wrong? But I'll definitely remember natsort.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to sort by length of list, then by the list itself.

You can do this with [`numpy.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html). Here's a minimal example.

```
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([[0], [1], [2], [0, 4], [3, 6], [0, 3]])

res = np.lexsort((s, s.str.len()))

# array([0, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

So you can do this with your dataframe:

```
df = df.iloc[np.lexsort((df['a'], df['a'].str.len()))]
```

Just be careful, `np.lexsort` syntax works from right to left, i.e. sorting is performing first by length with the above logic.